# Ruby program not displaying properly in terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, display, puts

I am writing very basic Ruby programs to learn. I wrote the following:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

When I run this program in my terminal this happens:

```
Hello world%
```

Why there is a `%` at the end ? That's never happens before during my practise.

Comment: Is your actual program `print "Hello world"` rather than `puts "Hello world`?

Comment: @mikej I don't follow. How would that cause the output?

Comment: @SagarPandya The trailing `%` could be printed by zsh rather than by Ruby. By default zsh prints a `%` when the last line of output doesn't have a newline (which is the case when using `print` vs `puts`.)

Comment: [Detailed explanation here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582/218427).